# How to upload mutiple files to nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I want to multiple files on nginx, I use the script which to perform saving one file(code below). I want to send a form with multiple files to save theirs on the server. How can I change my script?

```
  location /someurl {
    limit_except POST          { deny all; }

    client_body_temp_path      /www/mydir/images;
    client_body_in_file_only   on;
    client_body_buffer_size    128K;
    client_max_body_size       1000M;

    proxy_pass_request_headers on;

    proxy_set_header Host               $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $remote_addr;

    proxy_set_header           X-FILE $request_body_file;
    proxy_set_body             off;
    proxy_redirect             off;
    proxy_pass                 myurl;

   }
```